# How can i convert ternary operator If structure?

Tags: c#

I am super beginner at the programming and have a quick question.

i have this code and i want convert it to IF structure but i confused little bit. Can anybody help me to convert it?

```
var selectedCategoryId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId5)
    ? string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId4)
        ? string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId3)
            ? string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId2) 
                ? categoryId1 
                : categoryId2
            : categoryId3
        : categoryId4
    :categoryId5;
```

Check it up on google

Comment: Show how you failed and we will fix that. Don't ask us to write it for you.

Comment: At least it's indented. But clicking the light bulb(in vs ) 4 time should do the trick. t

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_conditions.php

Comment: Have an array of properties, `new []{categoryId1,2}`, And take the first one that is not null nor empty

Comment: Your code currently displays so called 'Arrowcode' due to its indentation. Here is a good article about why that is bad and how to prevent this: https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/amp/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

select the `FirstOrDefault()` which is not `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`

```
string[] input = { categoryId5, categoryId4, categoryId3, categoryId2, categoryId1 };
var result  = input.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Comment: Probably `.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x), categoryId1);` for the edge case when all ids are *empty strings* we want an *empty string* (not `null` which is default) as a result